# get monthly sum in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I have two arrays in laravel containing first day of every month for current year and previous year.

```
$current_month = new \Carbon\Carbon('first day of this month');
    $prevyear_month = new \Carbon\Carbon('first day of this month last year');

    $current_year = array();
    $prev_year = array();

    array_push($prev_year, $prevyear_month->toDateString());
    array_push($current_year, $current_month->toDateString());

    for($i = 1; $i<12; $i++)
    {
        $temp = $current_month->addMonth();
        $temp_prev = $prevyear_month->addMonth();

        array_push($current_year, $temp->toDateString());
        array_push($prev_year, $temp_prev->toDateString());
    }
```

this is the outcome

```
Array ( [0] => 2016-03-01 [1] => 2016-04-01 [2] => 2016-05-01 [3] => 2016-06-01 [4] => 2016-07-01 [5] => 2016-08-01 [6] => 2016-09-01 [7] => 2016-10-01 [8] => 2016-11-01 [9] => 2016-12-01 [10] => 2017-01-01 [11] => 2017-02-01 ) 
Array ( [0] => 2015-03-01 [1] => 2015-04-01 [2] => 2015-05-01 [3] => 2015-06-01 [4] => 2015-07-01 [5] => 2015-08-01 [6] => 2015-09-01 [7] => 2015-10-01 [8] => 2015-11-01 [9] => 2015-12-01 [10] => 2016-01-01 [11] => 2016-02-01 )
```

I'm trying to get sum of all those months, but don't know how to go about it.  I'm fine with doing raw query if thats the way to go.

Table has rows for every single day. with date column (carbon style ex. 2016-01-01) and column for revenue. I'm trying to get sum of revenue for every month in arrays above.

Comment: oh sorry forgot to mention, i have table where date column is carbon style date (ex 2016-01-01) and revenue column. i need to get sum of revenue column for each month, basically how much in revenue i had every month from that array i have generated.

Comment: yes ill go ahead and update the question, and table rows are every single day

Comment: ok so im generating the arrays with list of dates (they are all first of the months), for past year and this year.  so for example in array first date is 2016-01-01, so i need to get total revenue i made in month on jan, 2016.

Comment: are you looking for each month's total revenue for the past two years? give an example of an expected output you are hoping to achieve

Comment: ok so my database table has revenue for every single for past 3 years up to next year . so what i need to do is show the revenue for each month for this year and previous year on the webpage, so we can see how we are doing compared to previous year. so if you look at the two arrays in my original question it has 12 dates in it, i need to grab each date and get the total of that month. for example first date in array is 2016-03-01 so i need to sum up revenue of march, that is start from march 1 2016 to end of march get sum of column named revenue

Comment: i just need query to sum up specific column for given month, and have the output grouped by year and month

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to clean this up a bit, but here is a good start for how you can accomplish this.

The following is an example function I just wrote that you can adapt and add to your Model:

```
public function getMonthlySum(Carbon $date)
{
    $year = $date->year;
    $month = $date->month;

    if ($month < 10) {
        $month = '0' . $month;
    }

    $search = $year . '-' . $month;

    $revenues = parent::where('date', 'like', $search .'%')->get();

    $sum = 0;
    foreach ($revenues as $revenue) {
        $sum += $revenue->revenue;
    }

    return $sum;
}
```

This will calculate the sum of the revenues for any entry in the table that has the same year and month as the $date passed as the argument.

You should be able to adapt this to work with your code, as well as tweak it slightly for any other sums you want to calculate, such as `getYearlySum`.

Comment: thanks, that will do the job, i think this might work better rather that sql query and groupby and all that crap